# How to implement message class with configurable bit as either 0 or 1 in C++?

Tags: c++, class, message, bit

I am trying to create a message class with configurable as either 0 or 1 such as this

```
1 Byte, unit 8
Bit 0: Port A, 1 connected, 0 disconnected
Bit 1: Port A, 1 connected, 0 disconnected
Bit 2: Port A, 1 connected, 0 disconnected
Bit 3, 4, 5, 6, 7: Reserved
```

This I have been able to implement using union and type punning in C++ but this is seen as undefined behavior in C++.

```
union Msg{
    uint8_t bitfield;
    struct {
        uint8_t PORTA : 1;
        uint8_t PORTB : 1;
        uint8_t PORTC : 1;
        uint8_t : 5;
    } msg;
};
```

**How can I do this in C++?**

And is it possible to create a function to pack data into this structure?

Comment: Just use bit shifts and masks

Comment: Use the bitwise operators, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `~`. There are plenty of guides online about bit manipulations.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't catch what you want! What you would achieve with a "message"? Should it be something like switch on /off a portpin and port and portpin should be part of the message? As you have a bit for PORT A/B/C it seems not to be a bit per pin or something like that... totally unclear what you are talking about!

Comment: Is there something that won't work with a bitset? https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise operations. First, define helper functions for getting/setting a bit:

```cpp
bool get_bit(uint8_t bits, uint8_t index) {
    return bool((bits >> index) & 1U);
}
uint8_t set_bit(uint8_t bits, uint8_t index, bool value) {
    return (bits & ~(1U << index)) | (uint8_t(value) << index);
}
```

Then, you can use `uint8_t` instead of `Msg` or define `Msg` as an alias for `uint8_t`.

```cpp
// Msg is an alias for uint8_t
using Msg = uint8_t;
Msg message = 0;

message = set_bit(message, 0, true); // Setting the PORT A on
message = set_bit(message, 1, true); // Setting the PORT B on
message = set_bit(message, 2, false); // Setting the PORT C off
// You can use 1 or 0 instead of true or false
message = set_bit(message, 0, 0); // Setting the PORT A off

bool port_b = get_bit(message, 1);
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::bitset` ([docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)) which does the bit manipulation for you:

```cpp
// You choose the number of bits at compile-time
std::bitset<3> ports;
ports[0] = true;
ports[1] = false;
ports[2] = ports[1];
```